# How to exclude golang tests, structs and constants from counting against code coverage in SonarQube?

Tags: go, sonarqube

SonarQube 7.3 it has inbuilt support for golang where I have found at least 2 issues :-

It does not exclude *_test.go automatically from coverage. In unit tests it also picks up IP addresses and asks them to be made configurable (not constant which also does not fix the error).

It counts structs and const as not covered lines and hence has a significantly lower % covered than the go coverage tool itself making it a bad use case. For example in a medium size project it reports 40% coverage against go tools 70%

Apart from commenting them all to be sonar exclude or putting constants and structs  in a common exclude pattern file is there something else that can be done? Is there a plan to address these in a later version of SonarQube?

Answer (score 3):

For now (SonarQube 7.4), SonarGo analyzer does not identify automatically `*_test.go` as test files. This is a missing feature, this is why the [SonarGo documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarGo) describes how to properly identify test files through settings:

`sonar.test.inclusions=**/*_test.go`

Without proper test identification, the coverage result will be wrong and the analysis result could raise issues that do not make sense (like hard-coded IP addresses in tests).

About the coverage accuracy (for files that are not test files), there's two cases:

- If a file has entries related to it in the coverage report, the covered lines shown in SonarQube should match exactly the ones in the report, otherwise it's a major bug. But the *percentage* shown by go tools (ranges coverage) could be slightly different that the percentage shown in SonarQube (lines coverage), e.g: +2%.
- If a file is not in the coverage report, SonarGo generate a 0% coverage based on its definition of *executable line of code*. If there's a difference with `go test` definition of *executable line of code*, it's a bug that will disappear once the file is partially covered.

The best way to have those coverage bugs fixed, is to report them at [community.sonarsource.com](https://community.sonarsource.com/) by creating a `Report a Bug` topic with a small code reproducer.

Comment: Is it possible to add a known bug just to confirm that sonarqube can catch it? A pointer is much appreciated.

Comment: `x =+ 2` (instead of `x += 2`) or just `// TODO` comment

Comment: Okay! I did a `return` with statements after it, sonar caught it. But when I did `for {}`, sonar didn't!